# Sed command in a script to find a string if exists else append with new string

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to insert a string after finding a certain string to file called xyz.txt.

Here is the xyz.txt file:

```
/virtualhosts
    {
        "alsed-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "ecaas-fr-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "dvdvd-in-agency-starter.abc.com"
    }
```

Here I have insert a new string "geg-de-starter.abc.com" as below:

```
/virtualhosts
    {
        "geg-de-starter.abc.com"
        "alsed-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "ecaas-fr-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "dvdvd-in-agency-starter.abc.com"
    }
```

How can do this using sed (or any other way)?

Comment: Please post what you've done so far to solve the problem. Also what is the string that you're looking for?

Comment: Insert "geg-de-starter.abc.com"  on what condition? where?

Comment: insert "geg-de-starter.abc.com"

will be as as follows where domain value is geg-de

if grep -Fq "${domain}" publish-settings.any
then
   echo " # Domain  exists  "
   exit
else
 sed -i 's/^virtualhosts\{ .*$/virtualhosts '${domain}/' publish.any
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v newStr='"geg-de-starter.abc.com"' '
    NR==FNR { if ( index($0,newStr) ) gotNew=1; next }
    index($0,"/virtualhosts") { gotBeg=1 }
    !gotNew && gotBeg && /"/ {
        indent = $0
        sub(/".*/,"",indent)
        print indent newStr
        gotBeg = 0
    }
1' file file
/virtualhosts
    {
        "geg-de-starter.abc.com"
        "alsed-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "ecaas-fr-agency-starter.abc.com"
        "dvdvd-in-agency-starter.abc.com"
    }
```